# JQuery on Change event for textbox class not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a class of textboxes and trying to attach onChange event to the class. Code below works and i get the output from calData in firefox but does  not work on Chrome

```
enter code here
    <ul id="week_list">
        <li id="34">
            Week 1 - <input class="test_class" type="number" id="week_34" name="week[]">
        </li>
        <li id="35">
            Week 2 - <input class="test_class" type="number" id="week_35" name="week[]">
        </li>
    </ul>

   //Javascript

 var Test =
 {
     init: function(config) {
         this.bindEvents();
     },   
     bindEvents: function() {
         this.config.clTest.on('change',this.calData);
     },
     calData: function(){
         console.log("calculating");
     },
 };

 Test.init({
     clTest: $('.test_class'),
 });
```

Comment: err... obvious question, what does the console say in chrome?

Comment: It does not print anything from calData. However in Firefox it does. It does go through init and bindevents in both cases

Comment: Interesting, on my version of chrome it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clTest' of undefined ".  I'd say fix that, @Nir has a way.

Comment: But i dont get the error in FF. Not sure how to enable the strict error logging in chrome like you have.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your js to be something like this

```
var Test = 
 {
     config:null,     
     init: function(c) {

         config = c;
         console.log(config);
         this.bindEvents();
     },   
     bindEvents: function() {
         config.clTest.on('change',this.calData);
     },
     calData: function(){
         console.log("calculating");
     }
 };

 Test.init({
     clTest: $('.test_class'),
 });​
```

forgot to include the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sznj3/11/)

Comment: I tried following as per your advice. It prints the objects in FF but not it chrome. No errors in FF as well. In chrome just the string messages are printed
var Test =
{
   config: null,
   init: function(c) {
      console.log("init");
      this.config = c;
      console.log(this.config);
      this.bindEvents();
   },
   bindEvents: function() {
      console.log("binding..");
      console.log(this.config.clTest);
      this.config.clTest.on('change',this.calData);
   },
   calData: function(){
      console.log("calculating");
   },
};
Test.init({
   clTest: $('.test_class'),
});

Comment: I just ran the demo in chrom and it worked fine for me. There is an extra console.log in the init that you might want to remove